# Amazon aws snapshots and AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

I am new at Amazon services so I need some questions to ask...
Before upgrading to a newer instance I created an AMI of the current instance. 
Can I delete that AMI now after successful upgrading, without damaging the isntance?
Also, can I delete my snapshots, created from the running instacens volumes?

Is a AMI(Image) or snapshot being used by a working instance or is it sepearated and represents only a backup alternative?

It is a windows server instance

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I delete that AMI now after successful upgrading, without damaging the instance?

Yes, You can.

> Also, can I delete my snapshots, created from the running instance volumes?

Yes, You can.

> Is a AMI(Image) or snapshot being used by a working instance or is it separated and represents only a backup alternative?

The instances are independent of the AMI/Snapshots. So no worries. You can delete AMI/Snapshot without affecting Running instances.

You can create new instances using AMI. And you can create a volume OR an AMI using a snapshot. So YES, in a way it can be treated as a backup option.

Comment: Can I delete the instance the AMI is created on?

Comment: @JudyJiang, Yes, you can.

Comment: @JudyJiang, care to upvote my answer if you find it helpful. thanks.